# how to setup django-mongodb inside docker using djongo engine

Tags: django, docker

docker-file:

```
FROM python:3.6

WORKDIR /usr/src/jobsterapi
COPY ./ ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  #Backend API
  jobsterapi:
    container_name: jobsterapi
    build: .
    command: python src/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    working_dir: /usr/src/jobsterapi
    links:
      - mongodb
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
        - ./:/usr/src/facerecognition-api

  mongodb:
    restart: always
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: "mongodb"
    environment:
    - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${soubhagya}
    - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${Thinkonce}
    - MONGODB_USERNAME='soubhagya'
    - MONGODB_PASSWORD='Thinkonce'
    - MONGODB_DATABASE=='jobster'
    volumes:
    - ./data/db:/var/micro-data/mongodb/data/db
    ports:
    - 27017:27017
    command: mongod --smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null # --quiet
```

django-database setting:

```
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'djongo',
            'NAME': 'jobster',
            'user': 'soubhagya',
            'password':'Thinkonce',
            'port': 27017
        }
    }
```

i don't know actually how to setup django with mongodb inside docker-compose. i am trying from some blogs by this way. but it is not working.

please have a look into my code.

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in your environment:

```
- MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${soubhagya}
- MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${Thinkonce}
- MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=='jobster'
```